# Drupal 9 custom module to download file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-9

I want to write custom module to send file to browser, but I don know how to do it. How the DefaultControler of the module should be written? I think about something like this:

```
class DefaultController extends ControllerBase 
{

private function go()
{
   ob_clean();
   $gen = new SomeFileGenerator();
   $gen->downloadFileAs('xxx.yyy'); //send file to browser
   return 'File was sent';
}

  public function start() //function defined in mymodule.routing.yml as main controller function
  {
    \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->go(),
    ];
  }

}
```

I thing that is not valid way, so please tell me how should i do it?

//I am noob in drupal/php ;), but is my hobby project, professionally I write low level c/c++ programs

Comment: If I understood you well (you want to provide an url which will manually send the file when called) then this should be helpful I believe: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253636/how-do-i-create-a-file-download-url

Comment: And also this: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/serve-pdf-download-controller-drupal-8 and 

https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/custom-data-file-responses-drupal